# Deleting last item on the list

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple HTML unordered list and a JavaScript function that adds items at position [0], and another that deletes items at [0] as well, but what can I add to the delete function (strictly basic JavaScript please even if it's longer) so it deletes the last added item? Thank you in advance:

**HTML:**

```
    <html>

    <body>

       <h1> Shopping List </h1>


        <button onclick="adding()"> Add </button>

        <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter Items"> </input>

        <button onclick="remove()"> Remove Last </button>


        <ul id="list">


        </ul>


    </body>

</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function adding() {

 var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
 var newEl = document.createElement("li");
 var newText = document.createTextNode(input);

 newEl.appendChild(newText);

 var position = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0]; 
 position.appendChild(newEl);



 document.getElementById("input").value = "";

}

 function remove() {
 var removeEl = document.getElementsByTagName("li")[0];
 var containerEl = removeEl.parentNode;
 containerEl.removeChild(removeEl);

 }
```

Comment: why not use JQuery. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_last.asp

Comment: I know it would be easier for sure, but I haven't touched Jquery yet and this is an exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function adding() {

 var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
 var newEl = document.createElement("li");
 var newText = document.createTextNode(input);

newEl.appendChild(newText);

var position = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0]; 
 position.appendChild(newEl);



document.getElementById("input").value = "";

}

function remove() {
 var els = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
 var removeEl = els[els.length - 1];            // <-- fetching last el
 var containerEl = removeEl.parentNode;
 containerEl.removeChild(removeEl);
 }
```

```html
<html>
<h1> Shopping List </h1>


<button onclick="adding()"> Add </button>

 <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter Items"> </input>

<button onclick="remove()"> Remove Last </button>


<ul id="list">


</ul>


</body>

</html>
```

If `els` is an array, it has indices from `0` to `els.length - 1`. `0` is the first, `els.length - 1` is the last index.

Besides, try not to use attribute event handlers like `onclick="adding()"`. A much better practice is to attach them programmatically, for clean separation of concerns:

```
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

and then

```
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', adding);
```

Comment: Simple and just what I wanted, thank you. And thanks for the explanation too. I'll change it to an eventListener.

Comment: If there aren't any `li` then crash on remove.

Comment: What can you do about that?

Comment: Test if `els` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Purely speaking this answers the question as it **only** removes the last added item then won't remove anything else

```
window.lastadded = false;
function adding() {

 var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
 var newEl = document.createElement("li"); 
 newEl.id = Date.parse(new Date());
 var newText = document.createTextNode(input);

window.lastadded = newEl.id;

newEl.appendChild(newText);

var position = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0]; 
 position.appendChild(newEl);


document.getElementById("input").value = "";

}

function remove() {
 lastElement = document.getElementById(window.lastadded);
lastElement.parentNode.removeChild(lastElement);
 }
```